# How do I fire backwards in a plane without flying upwards?

Tags: sonic-all-stars-racing-transformed

When playing with a controller, I can fire certain items backwards certain by holding down on the left stick before pressing the fire button. This works fine when driving a car or boat, but holding the stick down in a plane causes me to fly upwards.

How do I fire a weapon backwards from an airplane without flying upwards?

Answer (score 1):

You can look behind you and then fire, this makes the weapon fire backwards without changing your trajectory.

To look back simply press:

- <kbd>□</kbd> on PS
- <kbd>X</kbd> on Xbox
- <kbd>Y</kbd> on Switch